# Magento 2 : Mini-cart quantity update button not working properly

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Firstly I have added 1 product to my cart.
When I am clicking on mini-cart then it shows like following:

[image]

Now when I am updating **QTY = 4** then clicks on **Update** button then 1 ajax call triggers and in that ajax call item_qty parameters not updating like in below image :

[image]

Update quantity button and input fields come from below file:
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

```
             <div class="details-qty qty">
                <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                       for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                <input data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       'data-item-qty': qty,
                       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                       }, value: qty"
                       type="number"
                       size="4"
                       class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                       maxlength="12"/>
                <button data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       title: $t('Update')
                       }"
                        class="update-cart-item"
                        style="display: none">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Related js file is located at:
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js**

What should I do to update quantity from their?

Comment: Hi @Nitesh i have same issue is there any update?

Comment: @AkshayThakkar I am unable to remember now but I think this was a bug of magento, so please check same type of issue on github, may be you can find solution or patch for it.

Comment: Hi @Nitesh thanks for update and i will check in core issue

Comment: @AkshayThakkar ever any resolution to this? Facing the same issue myself now.

Comment: Hi @ne0nlight please check in your theme default.xml file if you move minicart issue maybe face because of these.